Circuit-level noise and decoding graphs
I'd like to check if my understanding is correct.
Given $n$ rounds of some syndrome extraction circuit that are performed consecutively, building a decoder for circuit-level noise involves the following steps:
Offline phase:

Independently inserting a Pauli X or Z error on each register (data and ancilla) between any two gates of that full syndrome extraction circuit
Propagating that error through the circuit and checking what syndromes they trigger and storing this information somewhere

Online phase:

Upon seeing an actual syndrome, the decoder decides which was the most likely subset of events from 1. that caused that syndrome
Apply the relevant correction to the circuit

If the above is correct, isn't step 2 of the offline phase extremely inefficient for larger circuits?
In the case of an example Stim circuit for the surface code, does it actually carry out these steps in the process of building detectors or is something different being done?

Step 2 is stim.Circuit.detector_error_model().
Assuming the user has declared which measurements are compared to perform the checks, then no it's not expensive. In the typical case it's linear time. The key is not to track errors forwards, but instead to track checked measurement sets backwards, with each qubit storing which checked sets have a non-identity term on that qubit at the current time while travelling backwards. Then for each error you just lookup the relevant sets by the qubits the error touches, and see which ones it anticommutes with.
The typical performance is $O(\text{gates} + \text{errors})$, because most error correcting codes have each qubit protected by O(1) detectors at any one time. If you have a code that violates this then the worst case performance is $O(\text{detectors} \cdot (\text{gates} + \text{errors}))$.
Note that, for loops, you can use the tortoise and hare algorithm to determine when the detectors have become periodic. Stim implements this optimization, which is why it can turn a thousand-round surface code circuit into a detector error model as fast as it turns a ten-round surface code circuit into a detector error model. Though, that said, non-realtime decoders like pymatching tend to unroll the detector error model which loses almost all the benefits of doing that.

What is a checked measurement set? Is there an example of this backward propagation of a checked measurement set in the Stim repo?

@user1936752 It's a detector. Read https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.02192 for examples.
